# How to do queries on a collection of actors

Tags: akka, akka.net

I have an actor system that at the moment accepts commands/messages. The state of these actors is persisted Akka.Persistance. We now want to build the query system for this actor system. Basically our problem is that we want to have a way to get an aggregate/list of all the states of these particular actors. While I'm not strictly subscribing to the CQRS pattern I think that it might be a neat way to go about it.

My initial thoughts was to have an actor for querying that holds as part of its state an aggregation of the states of the other actors that are doing the "data writes". And to do this this actor will subscribe to the actors its interested to and these actors would just send the query actor their states when they undergo some sort of state change. Is this the way to go about this? is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation for implementing this type of pattern is to use a combination of pub-sub and push-and-pull messaging for your actors here.

For each "aggregate," this actor should be able to subscribe to events from the individual child actors you want to query. Whenever a child's state changes, a message is pushed into all subscribed aggregates and each aggregate's state is updated automatically.

When a new aggegrate comes online and needs to retrieve state it missed (from before it existed) it should be able to pull the current state from each child and use that to build its current state, using incremental updates from children going forward to keep its aggregated view of the children's state consistent.

This is the pattern I use for this sort of work and it works well locally out of the box. Over the network, you may have to ensure deliverability guarantees and that's generally easy to do. You can read a bit more on how to do that there: https://petabridge.com/blog/akkadotnet-at-least-once-message-delivery/

Comment: Thanks a lot! will go this route.

Answer (score 1):

Some of Akka.Persistence backends (i.e. those working with SQL) also implement something known as Akka.Persistence.Query. It allows you to subscribe to a stream of events that are produced, and use this as a source for [Akka.Streams](http://getakka.net/docs/streams/quickstart) semantics.

If you're using SQL-journals you'll need *Akka.Persistence.Query.Sql* and *Akka.Streams* packages. From there you can create a live (that means continuously updated) source of events for a particular actor and use it for any operations you like i.e print them:

```csharp
using (var system = ActorSystem.Create("system"))
using (var materializer = system.Materializer())
{
    var queries = Sys.ReadJournalFor<SqlReadJournal>(SqlReadJournal.Identifier)

    queries.EventsByPersistenceId("<persistence-id>", 0, long.MaxValue)
        .Select(envelope => envelope.Event)
        .RunForEach(e => Console.WriteLine(e), materializer);
}
```

Comment: I have a very strange behaviour: The RunForEach Method is awaitable and when i await for it, it prints out the events in the console but the method does not finish and creates a kind of dead-lock! (I'am using Postgresql as my DB)

Comment: Which query are you using? `EventsByPersistenceId` is live query. It means, it won't finish until a max sequenceNr will be reached. If you want to query only the data stored so far, use `CurrentEventsByPersistenceId` (or other methods starting with `Current...` prefix).

Comment: Using CurrentEventsByPersistenceId instead of EventsByPersistenceId was the solution! Thank you!